# Solspace Favorites for logged out members

Tags: solspace

Is there any way to allow logged out users to favorite an entry?

I understand the purpose of favoriting is to add the entry to their favorites list, but we'd like to use it for 'liking' functionality too for all users irrespective of whether they're a member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that is currently not available. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Although we haven't tried this ourselves, if there is an add-on that can "make guest members logged in", then perhaps you can use that as a workaround to allow guests to mark favorites. Again, never tried this ourselves so can't guarantee this would work.